# C++ Overloading Extraction Operator - Error cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, private-members, ostream

I'm working on some homework and receiving the strangest error. Hoping you can help. I am getting this error:

> Cannot access private member in class

**Note**: I am obviously not done writing this but I try to test for errors as I go. Thanks so much for any input you have!

```
// Amanda 
// SoccerPlayer.cpp : main project file.
// October 6, 2012
/* a. Design a SoccerPlayer class that includes three integer fields: a player's jersey     number,
number of goals, and number of assists. Overload extraction and insertion operators for     the class.
b. Include an operation>() function for the class. One SoccerPlayer is considered greater
than another if the sum of goals plus assists is greater.
c. Create an array of 11 SoccerPlayers, then use the > operator to find the player who   has the
greatest goals plus assists.*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>



class SoccerPlayer
{
    friend std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream, SoccerPlayer&);
//  friend std::istream operator>>(std::istream, SoccerPlayer&);
private:
    int jerseyNum;
    int numGoals;
    int numAssists;
public:
    SoccerPlayer(int, int, int);

};

SoccerPlayer::SoccerPlayer(int jersey, int goal, int assist)
{
    jerseyNum = jersey;
    numGoals = goal;
    numAssists = assist;
} 

std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream player,  SoccerPlayer& aPlayer)
{
    player << "Jersey #" << aPlayer.jerseyNum <<
        " Number of Goals " << aPlayer.numGoals << 
        " Number of Assists " << aPlayer.numAssists;
    return player ;
};

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ostream` is not copyable. You need to pass a reference, and return a reference:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const SoccerPlayer&);

....
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& player,  const SoccerPlayer& aPlayer) { /* as before */ }
```

Note also that there is no reason not to pass the `SoccerPlayer` as a `const` reference.

On a note completely unrelated to the error, you should prefer to use the constructor initialization list instead of assigning values to data members in the constructor body:

```
SoccerPlayer::SoccerPlayer(int jersey, int goal, int assist) 
: jerseyNum(jersey), numGoal(goal), numAssists(assist) {}
```

Comment: I see, thanks so much! I'm having a hard time with this chapter, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass and return the streams by reference: you can't copy IOStream objects. Also, in case of the write, you probably want to pass a `SoccerPlayer const&`. With these changes you code should compiler (although there is also an excess semicolon after the definition of the output operator).

That is, you output operator should be declared as

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, SockerPlayer const&)
```

(both in its definition and the `friend` declaration).

Answer (score 2):

You should send the reference of ostream object to your friend function.
So it will be something like `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, SoccerPlayer&);`
both in prototype as well as in definition.

Answer (score 0):

`std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream player,  SoccerPlayer& aPlayer)` has to be a friend of the class or a class member to access `private` and `protected` fields.

Comment: It _is_ a `friend`. The problem is the missing copy constructor on the stream objects (it would have been helpful if the question had mentioned what the exact error was).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I totally missed the friend part then.  Even though I looked twice.